# plugin backend help

Tags: plugin-development

this code is working perfect for me, but just want to know, how can i bring this after my post, currently all my tweets are coming before the post, how can i make it before the post??

```
    function parse_twitter_feed($feed, $prefix, $tweetprefix, $tweetsuffix, $suffix) {
  $feed = str_replace("&lt;", "<", $feed);
  $feed = str_replace("&gt;", ">", $feed);
  $clean = explode("<content type=\"html\">", $feed);

  $amount = count($clean) - 1;

  echo $prefix;

  for ($i = 1; $i <= $amount; $i++) {
    $cleaner = explode("</content>", $clean[$i]);
    echo $tweetprefix;
    echo $cleaner[0];
    echo $tweetsuffix;
  }

  echo $suffix;
}

function the_twitter_feed($username) {
  // $username = "Mba_"; // Your twitter username.
  $limit = "5"; // Number of tweets to pull in.

  /* These prefixes and suffixes will display before and after the entire block of tweets. */
  $prefix = ""; // Prefix - some text you want displayed before all your tweets.
  $suffix = ""; // Suffix - some text you want displayed after all your tweets.
  $tweetprefix = ""; // Tweet Prefix - some text you want displayed before each tweet.
  $tweetsuffix = "<br>"; // Tweet Suffix - some text you want displayed after each tweet.

  $feed = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:" . $username . "&rpp=" . $limit;

  $twitterFeed = get_transient($feed);
  if (!$twitterFeed) {
    $twitterFeed = wp_remote_fopen($feed);
    set_transient($feed, $twitterFeed, 3600); // cache for an hour
  }
  if ($twitterFeed)
    parse_twitter_feed($twitterFeed, $prefix, $tweetprefix, $tweetsuffix, $suffix);
}
function append_the_content($content) {
    $content .= the_twitter_feed(get_option('tweetID'));
       return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'append_the_content');

add_action('admin_menu','tweet_fetch');

function tweet_fetch(){
add_options_page('Tweet','Tweet', 8, 'tweet', 'tweet_fetcher');
}
function tweet_fetcher(){
?>
<h2>Tweet Fetcher options</h2>
<form method='post' action='options.php' style='margin:0 20px;'>
<?php wp_nonce_field('update-options'); ?>
<p>Twitter UserID:<input type="text" name="tweetID"  value="<?php echo get_option('tweetID'); ?>" <?php echo get_option('tweetID'); ?> />
</p>
<input type='hidden' name='action' value='update'/>
<input type='hidden' name='page_options' value='tweetID'/>
<p class='submit'>
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Update Options &raquo;'/>
</p>
</form>
<?php
}
```

Comment: There is no plugin header, no action hooks, actually there isn't even anything that shows me that you tried to do it. http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=how+to+write+a+wordpress+plugin

Comment: pluginn header i have not copy pasted over here, and what is action hook,
this plugin works if i use shot-code, but i just wanna have a backend

Comment: hey now i modified the code again, the options is also coming under settings options, see my original answer for the code, but the tweets are not coming please can any one help me in this

Comment: Might want to start here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: i saw that, and learned from there, but i just wanna know whats wrong in my code now???

Comment: There is no code for a backend... read the tutorials... http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Adding+Administration+Menus 1st result...

Comment: hey i made it, its working, everything is perfect, just one last question i wanna ask,
currently the tweets are coming, but it is coming before the post i want too make it after the post, how can i do that?
my new code is up, you can check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you want, but I noticed with position that echo not always give the right position try to build up a large string and then echo the complete results or just return the results.

like this:

$output .= echo $prefix;
$output .= echo $tweetprefix;
$output .= echo $cleaner[0];
$output .= echo $tweetsuffix;
$output .= echo $suffix;

return $output

if you want to do it with echo use comma's to seperate the strings like this:

echo $string1, $string2, $string3, etc.